# What does the interfaces in GraphQLInterfaceType?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I have the following the code snippet:

```
export const NodeInterface = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
  name: 'Node',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    }
  },
  resolveType: (source) => {
    if (source.__tableName === tables.users.getName()) {
      return UserType;
    }
    return PostType;
  }
});
```

and a `GraphQLObjectType` that is using the interface:

```
export const PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Post',
  interfaces: [ NodeInterface ],
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
      resolve: resolveId
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    body: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
    }
  }
});
```

For what do I have to define an interface?

Comment: Have you read the source code? It's just a class

Comment: I could not find it.

Comment: Really because it took me 4 seconds and I googled "GraphQLInterfaceType" http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlinterfacetype

Comment: But it does not mention how to use GraphQLInterfaceType in connection with GraphQLObjectType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GraphQL, interfaces fulfill two purposes:

1. They ensure that the types implementing them also implement specific fields. For example, the `Node` interface here has an `id` field -- that means any type that implements the `Node` interface will also need to have an `id` field (and that `id` will need to be an ID scalar like in the interface) The same goes for arguments on those -- any arguments on the fields in the interface will also have to exist on the matching fields in the implementing type.
2. They can be used when two or more types are expected for a field. A field will **always** resolve to exactly one type or scalar, however, by using interfaces (or unions) we indicate in our schema that the field **could** resolve to one of a set of types.

So let's say we have a `Node` like in your snippet, some types that implement it, and a query that returns a Node:

```
interface Node {
  id: ID!
}

type Foo implements Node {
  id: ID!
  someFooField: String!
  someOtherFooField: Int!
}

type Bar implements Node {
  id: ID!
  someBarField: String!
  someOtherFooField: Int!
}

type Query {
  getNode(id: ID!): Node!
}
```

In our example, `getNode` could resolve to either a `Foo` or a `Bar`. When we write our query, we don't know which one will be resolved. But because we know the `id` field is required by the interface, we can write a query like this:

```
query OperationName {
  getNode(id: "SOME_ID"){
    id
  }
}
```

If we need to query `someBarField` as well, though, we can't do this:

```
query OperationName {
  getNode(id: "SOME_ID"){
    id
    someBarField
  }
}
```

because `Foo` doesn't have that field. Instead we have to utilize a fragment, like this:

```
query OperationName {
  getNode(id: "SOME_ID"){
    id
    ... on Bar {
      someBarField
    }
  }
}
```

Then `someBarField` will be returned, but only if the field resolves to the type `Bar`. If it's a `Foo`, only id will be returned. Similarly, you can request non-shared fields from any type implementing the same interface:

```
query OperationName {
  getNode(id: "SOME_ID"){
    id
    ... on Bar {
      someBarField
    }
    ... on Foo {
      someFooField
    }
  }
}
```

Last but not least, it should be mentioned that unions work in a very similar fashion. However, unlike interfaces, there are no shared fields defined for a Union, so a type does not "implement" a union, it just is part of one. That means when requesting a field that returns a union, you'll always have to use fragments since there are no shared fields to request.

Comment: With `const NodeInterface = new GraphQLInterfaceType` do I create an interface, like `interface Node { id: ID! }`?

Comment: Yes, when defining a schema programatically in GraphQL.js, you typically define each type, interface, etc. as a variable so it can then be referenced by other types. Or if you want to use SDL (Schema Definition Language), you can look into graphql-tools